# How DB engine decides the query plan for JOIN operation?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, query-optimization

With the below schema:

```
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE movie (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, year INTEGER, nth TEXT, for_video BOOLEAN
  );
CREATE TABLE actor (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, gender TEXT
  );
CREATE TABLE role (
  movie_id INTEGER, actor_id INTEGER, name TEXT
  );
CREATE TABLE sqlite_stat1(tbl,idx,stat);
sqlite>
```

---

Running `JOIN` on two tables as shown below:

```
sqlite> select * from movie JOIN role ON (movie.id = role.movie_id) WHERE movie.title='Batman' LIMIT 1;
"id" "title" "year" "nth" "for_video" "movie_id" "actor_id" "name"
"47844" "Batman" "1989" "" "0" "47844" "84264" "Napier Hood"
sqlite>
```

For performance, I added below indexes:

```
sqlite> create index id1 on role(movie_id);
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> create index id2 on movie(title);
sqlite> 
sqlite>
```

---

and then the query plan says:

## Case 1

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select * from movie JOIN role ON (movie.id = role.movie_id) WHERE movie.title='Batman' LIMIT 1;
"selectid" "order" "from" "detail"
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE movie USING INDEX id2 (title=?)"
"0" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE role USING INDEX id1 (movie_id=?)"
```

## Case 2

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select movie.title, role.name from movie JOIN role ON (movie.id = role.movie_id) 
   ...> WHERE role.name = 'King Arthur' LIMIT 2;
"selectid" "order" "from" "detail"
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE movie USING COVERING INDEX id2"
"0" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE role USING INDEX id1 (movie_id=?)"
sqlite> 
sqlite>
```

---

For given two cases:

1. How does DB engine decide, that it needs to first search `movie` table and then search `role` table?
2. Why DB engine `SCAN`ning `movie` table in second case? instead of `SEARCH`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: @jarlh am using sqlite

Answer (score 1):

> How does DB engine decide, that it needs to first search movie table and then search role table?

Your `WHERE` clause asked for a movie by its `title` and for that there is an index, so surely it makes sense to go and get only the movies with that title first, then get their IDs, then get the roles with those IDs (for which there is also an indexed lookup), then join the few results together.

Going the other way round makes a lot less sense: get all 80,000 movies and connect them with say 1000 different roles to give a list of 80,000 movie roles, then throw them all away apart from the one with title X

This is an incredibly simplistic view on how a specific DB has planned this specific query; there are many different ways queries can be planned and executed. To explain every step and every decision an optimizer/planner takes would be way beyond the scope of an SO answer

---

For your second case SQLite looks to have come to the conclusion that it has to search by something that isn't indexed and it has to return two bits of data; one that is indexed and one that is not. It has decided on a strategy of pulling all the movie titles out of the index rather than the table (the index can provide the title and SQLite is preferring to use it to retrieve the data rather than the table), joining the movies to the roles based on the movie_id indexation in role, then filter all that work leaving just the King Arthur role name, and the associated movie title

> Why DB engine SCANning movie table in second case? instead of SEARCH

It's not searching the table, it's scanning the index, and it's performing a scan because the query doesn't ask for anything that is indexed so every value must be retrieved and compared to find what you're looking for

Comment: I have added another case in query, where it goes for `movie` first despite I gave WHERE clause on `role`

Comment: Are we going to have one of those questions where you ask, and we answer, and then you edit the question a bit, and we edit the answer a bit and you move the goalposts again, and we go round and round? Cos if we are, I'd prefer you to just read the fine manual for what it has to say about query planning  - https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html and https://sqlite.org/eqp.html

Answer (score 0):

Not mySql specific - so if MySQL is absolutely below par this works more like "left to right in your statement".

NORMALLY any databsae server has STATISTICS and estimages how many rows it will return for a given filter on which index, then it tries various approaches (all based on those statistics) to see which approach would be most efficient. And then it executes this one. As you filter by Movie.Title, it is quite likely it will do this first and then find the matching row in the other table.